# Spring MVC Test with Hamcrest: how count and test the properties number/size of an object inside a Model

Tags: spring, spring-test, hamcrest, spring-test-mvc

For Spring MVC Test (working together with Java Hamcrest):

Testing the scenario where is necessary render a jsp file with a `Model` object which only contains an instance of the `Person` class  I have the following (works fine):

```
.andExpect(model().size(1))
.andExpect(model().attributeExists("persona"))
.andExpect(model().errorCount(0))
.andExpect(model().hasNoErrors())

.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", notNullValue()))
.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", isA(Persona.class)))

.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", hasProperty("id", notNullValue())))
.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", hasProperty("id", is(persona.getId()))))
.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", hasProperty("nombre", notNullValue())))
.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", hasProperty("nombre", is(persona.getNombre()))))
.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", hasProperty("apellido", notNullValue())))
.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", hasProperty("apellido", is(persona.getApellido()))))
.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", hasProperty("fecha", notNullValue())))
.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", hasProperty("fecha", is(persona.getFecha()))));
```

I want to know if is possible and how, count the number of attributes/properties of the java object, in this case `Person` class.

I need this for the scenario when the `Person` class has new fields, i.e: as `age` and `height`. Therefore the test method should fail to let me update the `count` number and add

```
.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", hasProperty("age", notNullValue())))
.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", hasProperty("age", is(persona.getAge()))))
.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", hasProperty("height", notNullValue())))
.andExpect(model().attribute("persona", hasProperty("height", is(persona.getHeight()))));
```

Something similar how in `json` with

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$").exists())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(is(4))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int attrCount = model().getClass().getDeclaredFields().length;
assertThat(attrCount, equalTo(10));
```